# Can the "queryStringParameter" in the eventbody of a GET request be moved to the "body" of the event for an AWS API Gateway HTTP API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to get my "queryStringParameters" in the event into the "body" key of the event so I can parse them in the same way that I parse post requests. Is this possible with a HTTP api? I tried using parameter mappings in the integration settings but this only allows me to append the body to the queryString.

Answer (score 0):

The way that you get the values from a POST request using `body` and with query parameters are different. So both ca not be in the `body` property as you want.

The `queryStringParameters` is passed when you add a **URL Query String Parameter** in your Api gateway resource.

[image]

When you send a request to the event in your API the following event will be send to the Lamba function

```
{
    "resource": "/{proxy+}",
    "path": "/path/to/resource",
    "httpMethod": "POST",
    "isBase64Encoded": true,
    "queryStringParameters": {
        "foo": "bar"
    },
    "multiValueQueryStringParameters": {
        "foo": [
        "bar"
        ]
    },
    "pathParameters": {
        "proxy": "/path/to/resource"
    },
    "stageVariables": {
        "baz": "qux"
    },
    "body":"{ \"time\": \"evening\" }",
    "headers": {
    ...
    },
...
}
```

You be able to get the query parameters of event in your Lambda using the properties:

```
 event.queryStringParameters && event.queryStringParameters.foo
```

And the body we need to get with the `body` property:

```
if (event.body) {
    let body = JSON.parse(event.body)
    if (body.time) 
        time = body.time;
}
```

In this way in your Lambda you need to parse them in different ways.

For more information of how to work with API Gateway and Lambda take a look here: [Tutorial: Build a Hello World REST API with Lambda proxy integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-step-by-step.html)

Comment: I see. I was hoping to streamline my lambda function. Can they be moved to a custom parameter that I define?

Comment: You can create a query parameter and use as body, but I do not think that this is the best approach, also you can create a list to receive the values of the body and query in your lambda and use a specific function to handle it:

```let data = [];
data.push(event.queryStringParameters.foo)
data.push(event.body)```